# How to add a full angularjs web app into another web app project through node_modules or bower_components?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, npm, bower, angular-templatecache

I have developed a full angularjs web app that I need to Bower install or npm install it into another angularjs project. Do I need to bundle the whole app as one .js file e.g. templateCache.js that contains all the HTML codes in it or there is no need to bundle all into one .js but seperate index.css index.html index.js

Comment: You are in the right path. You can bundle the application and then include the bundle in the second application. You can create a node module and include it via package.json or if you're using git, you can put the git url in your bower.json file. And when you run the 2nd application the bower install has to run to get the files included in it.

Comment: Bundle the app html,css,js into one .js with angular-template-cache node_module or do you think it will also work by seperating the bundles to .html .css .js ...  I am currently providing the git URL in Bower.json ..

Comment: Angular-template-cache works by bundling all of them into one. That’s similar to what I am doing.